# .NET Dependency Injection with generic services that depend on other generic services

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

### Introduction

I started development with C# 2 months ago. Coming from a PHP background using Symfony I have knowledge about dependency injection and love generics so far, but the combination of the two confuses me a bit at the moment.

### Concept

I want to use a factory to create a specific instance of an `IHandler`. The `IHandler` can receive an `IParser<T>` which - as you can see - supports generics, so I have one interface for every possible parser. The factory will get a list of `IParser` which have a `SupportsParsing` method which will be called inside the factory to get the correct `IParser` and create a new `IHandler` with the chosen `IParser`.

### Code

#### IServiceFactory

```
public interface IServiceFactory<out T>
{
    T Create(string key);
}
```

#### EventHandlerFactory

```
public class EventHandlerFactory<T> : IServiceFactory<IHandler>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IParser<T>> _parsers;

    public EventHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IParser<T>> parsers)
    {
        _parsers = parsers;
    }

    public IHandler Create(string key)
    {
        foreach (IParser<T> parser in _parsers)
        {
            if (parser.SupportsParsing(key))
            {
                return new EventHandler<T>(parser);
            }
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### IParser

```
public interface IParser<T>
{
    List<T> Parse();
    bool SupportsParsing(string key);
}
```

#### EventCounterParser

```
public class EventCounterParser : IParser<EventCounter>
{
    public List<EventCounter> Parse()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool SupportsParsing(string key)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### EventLevelParser

```
public class EventLevelParser : IParser<EventLevel>
{
    public List<EventLevel> Parse()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool SupportsParsing(string key)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### IHandler

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle();
}
```

#### EventHandler

```
public class EventHandler<T> : IHandler
{
    private readonly IParser<T> _parser;

    public EventHandler(IParser<T> parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

#### Registering the services

So registering the parsers is easy

```
services.AddScoped<IParser<EventCounter>, EventCounterParser>();
services.AddScoped<IParser<EventLevel>, EventLevelParser>();
```

### Intention

But what I want to do now is:
 * Register the service factory
 * Register the handlers
 * Automatically inject all `IParser` instances into the `EventHandlerFactory`

And this is where it's getting hard for me. I don't really know how to register the services when it's using generics inside generics and also how to inject a generic `IList` or `IEnumerable` in here.

### Attempts

#### Own attempts

What I tried for the `IHandler`:

```
services.AddScoped<IHandler, Handler.Event.EventHandler<EventLevelParser>>();
services.AddScoped<IHandler, Handler.Event.EventHandler<EventCounterParser>>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceFactory<>), typeof(EventHandlerFactory<>));
```

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GenericDITest.Handler.IHandler Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHa
>   ndler`1[GenericDITest.Parser.Event.EventLevelParser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'GenericDITest.Parser.IParser`1[GenericDITest.Parser.Event.EventLevelParser]' while attempting to activate 'GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandler`1[GenericDITest.Pa
>   rser.Event.EventLevelParser]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: GenericDITest.Handler.IHandler Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandler`1[GenericDITest.Parser.Event.EventCounterParser]': Unab
>   le to resolve service for type 'GenericDITest.Parser.IParser`1[GenericDITest.Parser.Event.EventCounterParser]' while attempting to activate 'GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandler`1[GenericDITest.Parser.Event.EventCounterParser]'.)

So I tried to use the type specified registration

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler), typeof(Handler.Event.EventHandler<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceFactory<>), typeof(EventHandlerFactory<>));
```

but then I get the error

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandler`1[T]' for service type 'GenericDITest.Handler.IHandler'.

Sadly, I don't know enough about generics to really solve this issue. I don't really understand the error message. Maybe I'm defining the services wrong?

#### Attempts from other users

Like @user1672994 suggested, I made the following changes

`IHandler` to `IHandler<out T>`
`EventHandler<T> : IHandler` to `EventHandler<T> : IHandler<T>`   `EventHandlerFactory<T> : IServiceFactory<IHandler>` to `EventHandlerFactory<T> : IServiceFactory<IHandler<T>>`
`public IHandler Create(string key)` to `public IHandler<T> Create(string key)`.

Now, I can add the service as `services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(Handler.Event.EventHandler<>));` which now launches the application without any error, however because of all the generics, I now have to also register my factory like this

`services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceFactory<>), typeof(EventHandlerFactory<>));`.

But when I access the factory through `var service = provider.GetService(typeof(IServiceFactory<>));` I'm getting a new error. `Implementation type 'GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandlerFactory`1[T]' can't be converted to service type 'GenericDITest.Service.IServiceFactory`1[T]'`. But this I don't understand, since it's the same interface?

I also uploaded the project to a file hoster so you can check it out: https://mega.nz/#!jf51UALL!sbVrGSXoTtfzZLzOl9i7wwa-OC5s3xlhuf_RJuorIQs

Comment: The first error is pretty clear, you are trying to use `System.EventHandler`, which is BCL/CoreFX class, you have to use the correct namespace here

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I re-created the project (out of anothe rproject) and changed the classes to be more generic so everyone can understand it. I refactored my answer.

Comment: First, `ILogger<T>` works the way you want already: you only register the logging infrastructure but when you ask for a `ILogger<MyService>`, the DI container gives you the concrete logger you want. Second, the .NET Core code is available on Github, which means you can just [check the implementation.](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Logging)

Comment: [This file is interesting](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Configuration/src/LoggingBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs): It adds a generic type with `TryAddSingleton(typeof(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<>), typeof(LoggerProviderConfiguration<>));`

Comment: What if you convert `IHandler` to generic type and use the registration as  `services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(Handler.Event.EventHandler<>));`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The thing is, I'm never asking for a specific instance. The `EventHandler` shall get ANY implementation of `IParser`. But If I pass it as a constructor argument, I need to define a type, `IParser<T>`

Comment: @user1672994 You mean changing `IHandler` to `IHandler<T>`? Since T won't be used in the interface it is getting displayed as unused and doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Musterknabe - define like `IHandler<out T>`. See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/ILoggerT.cs) as reference

Comment: @user1672994 Okay, so I changed `IHandler` to `IHandler<out T>` so I also had to change `EventHandler<T> : IHandler` to `EventHandler<T> : IHandler<T>` (is this correct?) and also `EventHandlerFactory<T> : IServiceFactory<IHandler>` to `EventHandlerFactory<T> : IServiceFactory<IHandler<T>>` and the method `public IHandler Create(string key)` to `public IHandler<T> Create(string key)`. Now, I can add the service as `services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(Handler.Event.EventHandler<>));` which now launches the application without any error! (is this correct so far?)

Comment: So now I want to register my factory, however, because of all the generics, I now have to also register my factory like this `services.AddScoped(typeof(IServiceFactory<>), typeof(EventHandlerFactory<>));`. However, when I access the factory through `var service = provider.GetService(typeof(IServiceFactory<>));` I'm getting a new error. `Implementation type 'GenericDITest.Handler.Event.EventHandlerFactory`1[T]' can't be converted to service type 'GenericDITest.Service.IServiceFactory`1[T]'`. But this I don't understand, since it's the same interface? 
Thank you so much for yor help so far :)

Comment: @Musterknabe - Instead of `provider.GetService` why don't you use the dependency injection injected in constructor. I don't think you can create the object via code `provider.GetService(typeof(IServiceFactory<>))`. You need to provide the actual type in `IServiceFactory` to get the scoped instance.

Comment: Why are you even trying to register the `EventHandler<T>` via DI? Your factory will create the handlers explicitly with `new EventHandler<T>(parser)`, so they won’t be resolved through DI anyway.

Comment: @poke - You're right. Makes no sense. Removed the line.

Comment: @user1672994 - Because in the example, i have no other service where it's called. And if I have one, I need to define the factory as `IServiceFactory<T>` again. I have the feeling, this will clutter my code with `T` generics and hacky workarounds, because I have to use `T` everywhere I use one of these classes. Maybe I'm just having a bad approach. Can  you think of a better way to achieve what I want? You know the saying "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The EventHandler shall get ANY implementation of IParser

That’s not how generics work though. An `IParser<T>` is a completely separate type from some `IParser`. Unless you actually have a type hierarchy between them, they are completely unrelated. Generics can be a bit confusing here because a generic type isn’t actually a type that really exists. It’s only when you apply a concrete generic type argument, that there is a type.

So both `IParser<EventLevel>` and `IParser<EventCounter>` are real types (completely separate and *unrelated* ones though!), but the generic “template” for these types, `IParser<T>`, is not a concrete type.

You also have to understand that within a generic class, a generic type argument `T` will *always* refer to the exact same thing. That is basically a constant type that will be inserted at some point.

So your `EventHandlerFactory<T>` may have an `IEnumerable<IParser<T>>` but if you use the factory for example as `EventHandlerFactory<EventCounter>`, then that type will have an `IEnumerable<IParser<EventCounter>>`. So that’s also the type it will look for when resolving it via dependency injection. So it cannot get `IParser<EventLevel>` instances because those are unrelated to the type it is asking for.

An `EventHandlerFactory<EventCounter>` would only ever inject parsers for `EventCounter` and not other ones (which may not be what you were trying to do). And instead of using that type to also create handlers for `EventLevel`, you would have to use a *different* factory of the type `EventHandlerFactory<EventLevel>` (which has its own list of parsers for `EventLevel`).

---

It’s not entirely clear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish, especially since your implementations in your example are all empty, but if I were to guess, I would assume that you are just using too many generics here. So starting from the start, these are my assumptions:

- You have multiple parsers that can work with different types, but only ever one type per parser.
- You have a single event handler type that uses a compatible parser to handle some event of a type.
- You want a *single* factory that allows you to get the right event handler to handle your key.

Now there is a fundamental problem with your approach though: The parsers return a list of a concrete type, e.g. your `EventCounterParser` returns a list of `EventCounter` objects. If you now want to use that object within your event handler, then you will *need* separate event handler types to handle each of those results separately. Otherwise you have no common information to work with within your generic event handler.

What the right solution here is highly depends on what exactly you are trying to do with your parsers and event handlers. With the information we have that’s very difficult to address.

If we were to ignore that part of the parsers though, and the event handlers for example would just utilize the parser in a non-generic way, then you could reduce the setup to the following:

```
public interface IParser
{
    List<object> Parse();
    bool SupportsParsing(string key);
}

public class EventHandler : IHandler
{
    private readonly IParser _parser;
    public EventHandler(IParser parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }
    public void Handle()
    { }
}

public class EventHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IParser> _parsers;

    public EventHandlerFactory(IEnumerable<IParser> parsers)
    {
        _parsers = parsers;
    }

    public IHandler Create(string key)
    {
        foreach (var parser in _parsers)
        {
            if (parser.SupportsParsing(key))
            {
                return new EventHandler(parser);
            }
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
services.AddScoped<IParser, EventCounterParser>();
services.AddScoped<IParser, EventLevelParser>();
services.AddScoped<EventHandlerFactory>();
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I think I overthought the process and tried to make it way more generic than it's possible (without making everything generic). And you're right. Since the Parse methods return a list of objects, the handler wouldn't be able to handle it, unless I make it generic again. So you convinced me in a short time that this is not a good implementation.

Comment: And the only thing I'd need to change from your code is that I 1.) Implement the interface for the factory and 2.) change `List<object>` to `List<GenericObjectConvertedByParse>`. Whats' your opinion on this? I'd try your implementation then.

Comment: Yeah, I only left out the factory interface to save some space, but sure, you can have a non-generic interface for that factory. And yeah, if you have some other common “base result” type that `IParser` can return, then use that :)